# How to take read user input into a vector?

Tags: vector, input, rust

I want to take input from user in vector form, print it using a loop, and then reverse the vector through iteration.

```rust
use std::io;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let i = read_values::<f64>().unwrap();

    for a in i.iter().rev() {
        print!("{} ", a);
    }
}

fn read_values<T: FromStr>() -> Result<Vec<T>, T::Err> {
    let mut s = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut s)
        .expect("could not read from stdin");
    s.trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|word| word.parse())
        .collect()
}
```

```
4
4
```

It only takes 1 input. I want to take more than one and then reverse it.

Comment: The way `read_values` is written, it's meant to take multiple values in one line. e.g. `4 5 6 7 8`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question
whether the inputs are coming in line by line or in the same line with spaces.

Regardless, I am writing the answer for both cases.

#### 1. If inputs are coming in line by line:

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;

fn read_num<T>() -> T
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    std::io::stdin()
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .parse::<T>()
        .unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let input = read_num::<usize>();
    let mut line_vec = vec![0; input[0]];
    for ind in 0..input[0] {
        line_vec[ind] = read_num::<i32>()[0];
    }
    line_vec.reverse();
    for val in line_vec.iter() {
        println!("{}", val)
    }
}
```

#### 2. If inputs are on the same line with spaces:

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;

fn read_vec<T>() -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    std::io::stdin()
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse::<T>().unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<T>>()
}

fn main() {
    let input = read_vec::<usize>();
    input.reverse();
    for val in input.iter() {
        println!("{}", val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the double `unwrap()` method calls ? 
`... .lines().next().unwrap().unwrap().trim()...`

Comment: good question: `.next()` returns a `Result` wrapped in `Option`. The return type of `.next()` function is: `Option<Result<String>>`. [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Lines.html#method.next)

Comment: So to clarify, the first `unwrap()` gives the value of the `Option<T>` which is `Result<String>` but to get to the actual string we need to unwrap it one more time giving us the `OK(value)` of `Result<String>`.  
Am I getting that right?

Comment: @AlanRichards exactly right!

Comment: @AlanRichards you're welcome, you can always upvote the answer if you found it useful. Also its good practice to upvote the question as well.

Comment: -- Good heads up !

Comment: let input = read_vec::<i32>();
    for (i, val) in input.iter().enumerate() {
        let inputNumber: i32 = *val;
        println!("{} {}", i, inputNumber);
    }
for accessing both index and value of vector